# How can I find two missing probabilities given a PDF table and Expected Value?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If given the expected value $E(X) = 3.08$ of the following
[probability Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaJ8V.png):
$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
S &  a  &  b  &  c  &  \hphantom{0}d\hphantom{0}  &  \hphantom{0}e\hphantom{0}  &  \hphantom{0}f\hphantom{0}  &  g  &  h   \\ \hline
\text{PMF} & 0.04 & 0.05 & 0.01 & \color{red}?  & \color{red}?  & 0.2 & 0.05 & 0.03 \\ \hline
X &  1  &  2  &  3  &  4  &  5  &  6  &  7  &  8  \\
\end{array}$$
is it possible to determine $P(d)$ and $P(e)$?

I have attempted to solve this problem by summing all probabilities times their respective $X$, setting it equal to $3.08$, and solving for the missing probabilities. But since there are two of them missing, I can't solve for them.

The only way I can thing of is to assume that their probabilities are equal but the problem doesn't specify that they are.

How do you solve for $P(d)$ and $P(e)$, if possible?

Comment: you have two equations. One from the probability sum being $1$ and the other is the given expectation.

Comment: Is the distribution supposed to be continuous? Because if discrete, $X\cdot \operatorname{PDF} = 4.46$, assuming that $e=0$ and $d = 0.63$ (making the sum of the pdf = 1).